# How to read only Int from Char

Tags: c

I have a program that reads data from a text file and then stores it in a char. The file that is being read is formatted in a way that there is a series of numbers, blankspace, then a string of characters, and the file has over 150,000 lines. I want to take the numbers and store them in a Binary search tree, and have the string of characters be the key for each node. Right now I'm struggling to take the data from the char and sort it from the integers and characters.

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct treenode{
    struct treenode *lchild, *rchild;
    int id;
    char password;
}node;

void add(int id, char password){
    node *tree = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(tree == NULL){
        tree -> id = id;
        tree -> password = password;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    char temp = fgetc(fp);

    while (temp != EOF){
        printf("%c", temp);
        temp = fgetc(fp);
    }
    printf("\ntest");
}
```

Comment: When asking a question related to code, you should always add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Also, there are many existing questions about reading data from text files in C. Have you done any searching to see if there's an existing answer that can help? And your code contains no effort to *take the data from the char and sort it from the integers and characters* (whatever that means).

Comment: Note: `int fgetc()` returns an `int`.  Best to save result in an `int` (not `char`) to well distinguish the 257 different possible values.

Comment: `if(tree == NULL){    tree -> id = id;`  --> what!, its `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i am not able to understand what you are trying to do correctly,
But what i understood is that you want to check if value in temp if 0-9 then store it as integer, else store it as char. You can check the ascii value of tmp,

Example :

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main() {
>     vector<char> vChar;
>     vector<int> vInt;
>     char tmp = '1';
>     
>     if(tmp >= '0' && tmp <= '9') 
>         vInt.push_back((int)tmp);
>     else
>         vChar.push_back(tmp);
>         
>     printf("vChar Size: %d\nvInt Size: %d", vChar.size(), vInt.size());
> }
> ```

This will insert all '0-9' ASCII values in vInt vector, Rest all ascii Values Will inserted in vChar Vector.